# Display Search when any key is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently in the process of implementing a search similar to [Designspiration](http://designspiration.net/). When you're browsing the website and press any key the search field appears with your key already within it.

I'm already halfway in implementing this, just can't figure out how to do any keystroke. Below is what I've got so far which makes a full screen search appear when a button is clicked.

**Jquery**

```
$(function () {
    $('a[href="#search"]').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#search').addClass('open');
        $('#search > .search-container > form > input[type="search"]').focus();
    });

    $('#search, .search-container, #search button.close').on('click keyup', function(event) {
        if (event.target == this || event.target.className == 'close' || event.keyCode == 27) {
            $(this).removeClass('open');
        }
    });  
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="search">
<button type="button" class="close">×</button>
<div class="search-container">
    <span>Type to start Searching</span>
        <form class="search" method="get" action="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"     role="search">
            <input class="search-input" type="search" name="s" placeholder=""     autocomplete="off">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

How would I go about implementing search, so when a user just starts typing on the website the search box appears and the user starts typing within it?

Any help would be brilliant.

Comment: Apologies, forgot it was .net.

Comment: The basic flow could look like `$(window).on('keyup') ... store keycode in variable ... input.focus() ... use reference to keycode to update input.val`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about this? **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/eftd08eb/13/)**

```
$('#searchPage').fadeOut(0);
var isTypingInput=false,
    isSearching=false;
$('input').not('#theSearch').focus(function(){
    isTypingInput=true;
});
$('input').not('#theSearch').blur(function(){
    isTypingInput=false;
});
$(document).on('keyup',function(e){
    if(!isTypingInput && !isSearching){
        if(/([a-zA-Z0-9])+/.test(String.fromCharCode(e.which))){
            $('#searchPage').fadeIn(200);
            $('#theSearch').focus().val(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode));
            isSearching=true;
        }
    }
});
$('#searchPage').click(function(e){
    if($('#theSearch').is(e.target)) return false;
    $('#searchPage').fadeOut(200);
    isSearching=false;
});
```

you'll see that if you type inside the input on the page, the search will not appear.

also you can close the search page by clicking somewhere other than the searching input.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/rblakeley/8utrsfgp/

### jQuery

```
$(function () {
    var $field = $('.search-container input'),
        character;

    $(window).on('keyup', function (event) {
        if ($(event.target).is('input, textarea')) return;
        character = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);

        if (!$field.val().length) {
            $field.focus().val(character);
        }
    });
    
});
```

This isn't bullet-proof but it's a starting point.

Comment: Nice example. I would additionally add an `if ($(event.target).is('input, textarea')) return;` (right before `character = Str.....`) to prevent triggering Search stuff if one is i.e. filling a contact form :)